# Type 'CounterModel' does not conform to protocol 'PersistentModel` - SwiftData

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-data

I am trying to make a sample app which uses SwiftData to keep track of sports goals. I have a struct: `Team` which has values `id` (UUID), `name` (string), `score` (int), and `editing` (bool). I have a SwiftData model class which contains the values `id` (UUID), `teams` ([Team]), `pro` (Boolean). Normally, the class works fine without having the `teams` array in the `CounterModel` class, but as soon as I add `var teams: [Team]` to the class, I get the following errors:

- `Type 'CounterModel' does not conform to protocol 'PersistentModel'`
- `No exact matches in call to instance method 'getValue'`
- `No exact matches in call to instance method 'setValue'`

The class conforms to Identifiable, Hashable. The struct also conforms to these protocols. Conforming both to Codable does not make the error go away.
Here is my code if needed:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class CounterModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id = UUID()
    var teams: [Team]
    var pro: Bool
    
    init(teams: [Team], pro: Bool) {
        self.teams = teams
        self.pro = pro
    }
    func toTeamArr() -> [Team] {
        return teams
    }
    
}
struct Team: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var score: Int
    var editing: Bool = false
}
```

I have also tried putting the Team struct inside of the class. Same error.

Following a suggestion by a reply, Here is the updated code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class CounterModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id = UUID()
    @Relationship(.cascade) var teams: [Team]
    var pro: Bool
    
    init(teams: [Team], pro: Bool) {
        self.teams = teams
        self.pro = pro
    }
    func toTeamArr() -> [Team] {
        return teams
    }
}

@Model
class Team: Identifiable, Hashable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var score: Int
    @Transient var editing: Bool = false
    
    init(name: String, score: Int, editing: Bool = false) {
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
        self.editing = editing
    }
}
```

Now, there are only 2 errors produced:

- Type 'CounterModel' does not conform to protocol 'PersistentModel'
- Type 'Team' does not conform to protocol 'PersistentModel'

**Upon extracting the models into a separate Xcode project, it builds fine. When I bring the rest of my code into the project, it stops working. Will investigate further.**

Okay. It seems to be an issue with passing the data from the @Query modifier into different views. Upon removing the parameters for the `CounterModel` data model from the views, the app compiled fine. I'm assuming, and hoping that this is a bug. For now, I'll just query the data separately in the views. Thank you all for your help! I have submitted feedback on the issue, just in case: FB12338703

Comment: In your first example you could try to make Team conform to Codable, in the second you forgot to add the `@Relationship` macro that defines the relationship between the two classes.

Comment: @PaytonDev are you passing the CounterModel type into a view with a non-private var at any point?  This is what appears to trigger this for me, and I'm pretty sure this is a bug in SwiftData.

Comment: @BenHale nope. the initial query in ContentView is a private variable and is the center of all data for my app

Answer (score 3):

Okay. It seems to be an issue with passing the data from the @Query modifier into different views. Upon removing the parameters for the CounterModel data model from the views, the app compiled fine. I'm assuming, and hoping that this is a bug. For now, I'll just query the data separately in the views. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There are two changes you need to make to your model classes.

The first, is to change `Team` to a class and make it an `@Model`
The second change is to tell SwiftData that `teams` is a reference to another SwiftData entity using the `@Relationship` decorator.

```
class CounterModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id = UUID()
    @Relationship(.cascade) var teams: [Team]
    var pro: Bool
    
    init(teams: [Team], pro: Bool) {
        self.teams = teams
        self.pro = pro
    }
    func toTeamArr() -> [Team] {
        return teams
    }
    
}

@Model
class Team: Identifiable, Hashable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var score: Int
    @Transient var editing: Bool = false
}
```

The `.cascade` argument to `@Relationship` tells SwiftData to delete all of the referenced `Team` objects if the `CounterModel` object is deleted.

Comment: unfortunately the same errors occur. could this just be a SwiftData bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: By "the same error" do you mean the *Type 'CounterModel' does not conform to protocol 'PersistentModel'* ?  The code above compiles and runs for me.

Comment: Could it be that I'm adding an initializer to Team? the error "does not conform to protocol" is now happening on both Team and CounterModel.

Comment: No, I have your initialisers in my code.  It compiles and runs

Comment: It's something wrong on my end, then, because I have the code copy-pasted that you sent and it is just not compiling. I am getting Directory not found errors for <AppName>.swiftmodule. Would that be causing it?

Comment: Yes, that could be an unrelated beta Xcode issue that is causing the problem.

Comment: Note that OP forgot to use `@Relationship` when implementing this answer

Comment: My two cents' worth, this answer works for me as well, on MacOS 13.5, Xcode 15.beta, target ios17.